# How to launch the VStudio 'Launch Performance Wizard' option in browser different that IE?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

I'm trying to use the 'Launch Performance wizard' option from the 'Analyze' menu option in visual studio 2012. It is using Internet Explorer as the default browser. I need to change the default browser to 'Firefox' so when I launch the performance wizard, Firefox will open instead of Internet Explorer. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?